# How can I select non-unique fields and their sum in db2?

Tags: sql, db2, sum

I need to select unique codes and their sum(value) values. This does not work:

```
select distinct t1.code, (
    select sum(t2.value) from table2 t2
    where t2.code = t1.code
)
from table1 t1
```

example table:

```
Code Value
ABC  1
ABC  2
BCD  12345
```

expected:

```
Code Value
ABC  3
BCD  12345
```

actual:

```
Code Value
ABC  (null)
BCD  (null)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `GROUP BY` should suffice.

```
SELECT  Code, SUM(Value)
FROM    Table2
GROUP BY Code
```